# How to check if the result of an operation equals an Integer?

Tags: swift, integer

I'm super new with Swift (and programming). I need to compare if the result of a Remainder Operator (modulo operator) equals an integer.

This is my code:

```
if Int.random(in: 1...1000) % 4 >= "This number" {
  print ("OK")
} else {
    print ("WRONG")
}
```

If `"This number"` is replaced by an actual number e.g. `100` it works fine.
But if replaced by `Int` it crashes displaying: Type 'Int.Type' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: Welcome, okihand! Are you trying to test if the result of the remainder operation has the type integer, or has a particular integer value, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare Int with Int, not String or Int type (Int.Type). If you want to declare a value that you will use for comparison you can declare it as variable. To compare if it is equal use `==` operator.

```
let thisNumber: Int = 3 // or any other value
if Int.random(in: 1...1000) % 4 == thisNumber {
  print ("OK")
} else {
    print ("WRONG")
}
```

now both `Int.random(in: 1...1000) % 4` and `thisNumber` is Int so you can compare them without getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I think my main mistake was not knowing that the Remainer Operator will always result in an integer.